# Change GameWindow startup color to something else than default white?

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

When you instantiate a new `GameWindow`, its background color is white, I would like to change it to black for instance.

The problem is further visible if you have a long initialization sequence happening.

The closest I could get is to set clear color in constructor then swap but it ain't perfect.

```
using System.Drawing;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
using OpenTK.Mathematics;
using OpenTK.Windowing.Common;
using OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop;

internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var gws = new GameWindowSettings();
        var nws = new NativeWindowSettings
        {
            Size = new Vector2i(320, 240)
        };

        using (var game = new Game(gws, nws))
        {
            game.Run();
        }
    }
}

internal class Game : GameWindow
{
    public Game(GameWindowSettings gameWindowSettings, NativeWindowSettings nativeWindowSettings)
        : base(gameWindowSettings, nativeWindowSettings)
    {
        // close but still shows a white background at startup for some time
        GL.ClearColor(Color.Red);
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
        Context.SwapBuffers();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad()
    {
        base.OnLoad();
        GL.ClearColor(Color.Green);
    }

    protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnRenderFrame(args);
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
        Context.SwapBuffers();
    }

    protected override void OnResize(ResizeEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);
        GL.Viewport(0, 0, e.Width, e.Height);
    }
}
```

[image]

**Question:**

How to get `GameWindow` to use another color than white when it's first shown?

Comment: That white background comes from the [WNDCLASS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassa) from the WinAPI. It can be overridden, but I can only wish you luck doing it with OpenTK and C# sitting in the middle.

Comment: I guess you're right, I've tried to override wndproc to erase background, and while when you debug it's slow enough to update, in real time it has no effect at all.

Comment: Windows reverts to the brush defined in `WNDCLASS` if it can't get your application redraw itself in time. This is why overriding `wndproc` is not enough, particularly in situations like yours; i.e. when your code is busy in some initialization code and doesn't respond to messages. Another thing you can try is to create your window in a hidden state, and then show it after the initialization is complete.

Comment: The simplest fixes are always the best ones, showing the window only when initialization is done works perfectly, thanks!  